# Interfaces in Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

### What exactly is the use of specifying the parent class while not utilizing it?!

I am trying to implement Huber loss in TensorFlow. I've come across an implementation which you can check in the image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skEN9.png).
We can clearly see that we're not inheriting anything from the superclass(Loss module). Then what's the use of setting up **Loss** as a parent class and declaring **super.init** statement.

Comment: For implementing custom loss functions using classes in tensorflow 2, we have to inherit the `Loss` class from tensorflow.keras.loss. From the image we can see that they have added an additional attribute `threshold` and overrided the `call` method. You can refer the implementation of the `Loss` class [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py). If you are not comfortable with class based loss functions, you can implement function based loss functions in tensorflow 2 as well.

Comment: Yeah got it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Loss** is an abstract class and inheriting it means you have to override the call method or it will throw an error. You have overriden the parameters of the **init** in the HuberLoss function but still have to call super.init as some functions which TF might use internally like "_get_reduction" is implemented in the Loss class and the variables of that have to initialized which is done by super.init(). You can check the implementation [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.4.1/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py#L172-L186)